# Is Bast Kvothe's son?

Tags: the-kingkiller-chronicle, patrick-rothfuss

(Spoiler alert for *Kingkiller*) I reread *Kingkiller* the other day and I found that the term "Reshi," which is what Bast calls Kvothe, almost makes more sense for a father rather than a teacher, as many presume him to be. It would also not be a hard connection for Bast, who is known as the "Twilight Prince," to be the son of the "Twilight Lady" Ferulian, who Kvothe lives with for several months.

**Is there any other evidence that Kvothe is or is not Bast's father?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've just laid out all the evidence we have.

Comment: We just don't know that much about Bast.  Or Fae, despite glimpses.

Comment: "Bast, I am your father!  Search your feelings, you know it to be true!"  "All right, cool!"  "Someday, you will inherit this inn, and live here forever and ever..." "Nooooo!"

Comment: What is the reasoning behind `almost makes more sense for a father rather than a teacher`
It always seemed, to me, to be semantically equivalent to sensei.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the Book Bast is introduced as the son of Remmen, King of Twilight and the Telwyth Mael. There is a theory that Remmen could be a different name for Kvothe, who does have a number of names. However, in the Name of the Wind playing card deck there is art for Remmen. Pat approved all the art in the deck, which implies that Remmen, who is dark skinned and dark haired, is probably not Kvothe.
[Here is the art for the card of Remmen on the left and Bastas, or Bast, on the right](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e5/e0/84/e5e084b0b0f22e01e31977e813922419.jpg), I couldn't find a better resolution. [Here is a link to the Tinker's Pack site where you can buy the Faen deck Remmen is a part of](https://thetinkerspacks.com/products/pairs). I can't find a link for where it reveals Bast's parentage right now but it's on page 93 of my copy of Name of the Wind in the interlude *Flesh With Blood Beneath*. The quote is

> "Chronicler, I would like you to meet Bastas, **Son of Remmen**, Prince of Twilight and the Telwyth Mael. The brightest, which is to say the *only* student I've had the misfortune to teach. Glamourer, bartender, and, not last, my friend.

Comment: This is awesome! Before I accept could you give the actual quote or link to this passage?

Answer (score 18):

After the fight between Chronicler and Bast, Kvothe presents Bast as being a hundred and fifty years old which would make him much older than Kvothe himself.

> Chronicler stood impassively throughout the introduction, watching Bast as if he were a snake.
>
> “Chronicler, I would like you to meet Bastas, son of Remmen, Prince of Twilight and the Telwyth Mael. The brightest, which is to say the only student I’ve had the misfortune to teach. Glamourer, bartender, and, not last, my friend.
>
> “Who, over the course of **a hundred and fifty years of life**, not to mention nearly two years of my personal tutelage, has managed to avoid learning a few important facts. The first being this: attacking a member of the Arcanum skilled enough to make a binding of iron is foolish.”
>
> “He attacked me!” said Bast hotly.

Of course, it can still be due to the fact that time seems to flow more slowly in the Fae and Kvothe is then "converting" Bast's age into Earth years. It is currently hard to tell as we currently do not know how much time is stretched in the Fae.

Comment: I doubt that would be an issue given Kvothe's experience with time in that dimension.

Comment: Which is what I say at the end of my answer. We don't know and currently have no way of verifying it by calculation as we do not know the exact factor by which time is stretched since Kvothe can't remember precisely the time he spent in the Fae.

Comment: @holf - Kvothe didn't spend that long in the Fae.  When he returned to the world, he quickly found his group again and completed his current mission.  If he spent many decades in there, then most of the book's cast would have moved on/died.  For the book, it's pretty important that he remain in confluence with Denna.  I'm pretty sure that in real terms, he spent longer with the Adem than he did in the Fey.

Comment: @Pete - he indeed meets his group after less than an *Earth* week. But his beard has grown and he says that it has felt like month, maybe a year. If so, times flies fast in the Fae, maybe by a factor of 50 or more or less. I do not remember if we know how much time there is between his visit in the Fae and the present day (someone?), but it may be that Bast spent 150 years in the Fae but it was only 3 years or so on Earth.

Comment: @holf - I got the impression that time flows how it will in the Fae.  While it's possible that Bast stayed in there longer and aged slower, I'm not sure that concretes him as Kvothe's son.  We do know that Ferulian wasn't exactly chaste, even if she were Bast's mother.  It would be a bit of a plot-stretch in my opinion and probably not one that would add to the story.

Comment: There is also the Art of Remmen, King of Twilight and the Telwyth Mael, in the NotW playing card deck. Remmen is supposed to be Bast's father and the fact that there is Pat approved art of him being a purple skinned, black haired fey mean's Remmen is probably not a different name for Kvothe

Answer (score 2):

There's also the fact that bast's eyes change in colour with his emotions just like kvothe- could be just grasping at straws but my gut says he is the son of kvothe

Answer (score -1):

I also thought it peculiar that Pat would name him bast...as in bastard meaning illegitimate. He could be the adopted son of Remmen, and be the natural son of Kvothe. What we know about time and how it works in the fey realm we learn about in tWMF that it works differently than in the four corners. We are told in the book that there are stories of a person who goes missing for what seems like days only to return years later and vice versa. This could be true for Kvothe. It is estimated that he was gone for about a year, and while we dont know the gestation cycle of the fey creatures...unless Pat spoke to this in a convention or something, Felurian could have been pregnant when Kvothe left by their many couplings,  but didn't show.
I speculate that Bast is not Kvothe's student by chance. He is not a casual participant in the story. Bast is trying to get Kvothe to remember who he was so that he can make Kvothe keep his part of the bargain he made with Felurian to return to her. Whether this is to complete the family or not I can't say, I don't have a working theory behind Bast's goals beyond bringing Kvothe back to the fey and to Felurian.

Comment: This would be better made as a comment, rather than an answer.